# Its regarding Paypal using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I searched many sites I couldnt find solution for Paypal with codeigniter, most of the sites says to download from this link [CodeIgniter Wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PayPal_Lib/) but it is not showing anything to download library, so can any one give us the idea how to start implementing paypal in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution from AngelEye - here's the [intro article](https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/paypal-library-for-php-codeigniter-framework) and here's the [download link](http://www.angelleye.com/download-codeigniter-php-library-for-paypal-payments-pro/)